# Why make_nvp needs non-const reference?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

Why non-const reference here?

```
template<class T>
const nvp< T > make_nvp(const char * name, T & t);
```

The reason i'm asking is that i have a structure with public fields and i need to make them private and use accessors instead. So i would like to know if i'm allowed to use temporary variable and pass them to `make_nvp` or i need to befriend my serializer with the data structure.

```
// option 1
auto a = data.getA();
ar & make_nvp("A", a);

// option 2
ar & make_nvp("A", data._a); // _a is private, but serializer is friend
```

I don't know what is this `ar` because it's a templated parameter, so in some cases it could make use of this non-constness and save it for later use and then `option 1` is problematic.

Comment: In boost archive, you can use a single function for both serialization and deserialization. This is achieved by using the archive as template argument - it can be an output archive that serializes your structure or an input archive that loads your struct. For deserialization the function needs a non-const reference to store the deserialized value and that's why `make_nvp` needs a non-const reference.

Comment: @pschill i like your comment. You might want to turn into an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In boost archive, you can use a single function for both serialization and deserialization. This is achieved by using the archive as template argument - it can be an output archive that serializes your structure or an input archive that loads your struct from some file. For deserialization the function needs a non-const reference to store the deserialized value and that's why `make_nvp` needs a non-const reference.

Coming back to your question: Option 2 makes more sense, because option 1 breaks the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 breaks object tracking and is fine as long as you don't serialize any pointers to `data._a` or it's interior.